# jQuery Array is not being removed on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/gcke1msx/1/)**

Hi,

on click of images I'am passing the Image Name (attribute) to an Array, which is working fine, but whenever user click again to UnSelect, I'am trying to REMOVE Current Name($(this)), which is not happening, Instead Its being Removed Completely (Empty Array).
and also every time comma is appending for 1st element :-(

```
JS : 
 questionCount = 0;
        $('.q2 .product-multiple').on('click',function(e){
            if($(this).hasClass('selectTag')){
                questionCount--;
                $(this).removeClass('selectTag');

                removeItem = "Removing Clicked element Name -  " + $(this).find('img').attr('name')
                alert(removeItem);
            console.log("Should be Removed here.. " +" "+ getTagsNameArray)


            } 
            else {
                questionCount++;
                $(this).addClass('selectTag');
                getTagsNameArray = new Array();
                getTagsName = getTagsName + "," + $(this).find('img').attr('name');
                getTagsNameArray.push(getTagsName)
        console.log("Passing Value in Array - " +" "+ getTagsNameArray)

            }
            });

        $('.q2-get-answer').on('click', function(){
            getTagsName = getTagsName +" / "+ $('.q2-answer').find('.product-multiple.selectTag img').attr('name');
            alert(getTagsName)
            console.log(getTagsName);
        })


html : 
<div class="q2">
            <label for="q2">What type of symptoms that your child has?</label>
            <div class="q2-answer" id="q2">
                <div class="product-multiple">
                    <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="gassy">
                    <div>Gassy</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-multiple">
                    <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="fussy">
                    <div>Fussy</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-multiple">
                    <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="diahrea">
                    <div>Diahrea</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-multiple">
                    <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="spitup">
                    <div>Spit Up</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-multiple">
                    <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="constipation">
                    <div>Constipation</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="q2-get-answer">
                Q3 click me
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks for Answer!!

can i create a common function for this, as there are many questions with same functionality ? 
Any Thoughts ?

Thanks Again

Comment: What is the issue ? Unable to get it..

Comment: please check console.log() -> whenever the user select image "(name attribute) is being added in array" when user UNSelect Image (name attribute) has to remove from Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var getQ1Answer, getQ2Answer, getQ3Answer, getQ4Answer, getQ5Answer, getQ6Answer, sliderValue, selectMonth, q1answer, getTags;
var getTagsName = "";
var getTagsNameArray = new Array();
questionCount = 0;
$('.q2 .product-multiple').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('selectTag')) {
    questionCount--;
    $(this).removeClass('selectTag');
    var index = getTagsNameArray.indexOf($(this).find('img').attr('name')); 
    if (index !== -1) {
      getTagsNameArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
  } else {
    questionCount++;
    $(this).addClass('selectTag');
    getTagsNameArray.push($(this).find('img').attr('name'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare array outside the function. You pushed items in array with `,` which is not needed. Your JS code will look like:

```
var getQ1Answer, getQ2Answer, getQ3Answer, getQ4Answer, getQ5Answer, getQ6Answer, sliderValue, selectMonth, q1answer, getTags;
var getTagsName = "";
var getTagsNameArray = new Array();     // here you should create an array
questionCount = 0;
$('.q2 .product-multiple').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('selectTag')){
        questionCount--;
        $(this).removeClass('selectTag');
        removeItem = "Removing Clicked element Name -  " + $(this).find('img').attr('name')
        alert(removeItem);
        var doubleSelect = $(this).find('img').attr('name');
        var index = getTagsNameArray.indexOf(doubleSelect);
        console.log(index)
        if (index > -1) {
            getTagsNameArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
        console.log("Should be Removed here.. " +" "+ getTagsNameArray)
    } 
    else {
        questionCount++;
        $(this).addClass('selectTag');
        getTagsNameArray.push($(this).find('img').attr('name'));            //change is here
        console.log("Passing Value in Array - " +" "+ getTagsNameArray)
    }
});

$('.q2-get-answer').on('click', function(){
    getTagsName = getTagsName +" / "+ $('.q2-answer').find('.product-multiple.selectTag img').attr('name');
    alert(getTagsName)
    console.log(getTagsName);
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcke1msx/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a string to an array, which transforms the array into a string: getTagsName + ","
Instead of appending a string to the array, you need to add a new element to the Array by using getTagName.push($(this).find('img').attr('name')). You can remove items by using indexOf() and splice().
If you want to print the array, simply use getTagsName.join(). This will turn your array in a comma-seperated string.

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, you should not have so many variables. Just a variable to `push`/`splice` item `from/to` array.

[`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) => *The `splice()` method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.*

**Syntax:** `array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])`

```js
var getTagsNameArray = [];
$('.q2 .product-multiple').on('click', function(e) {
  var item = $(this).find('img').attr('name');
  if ($(this).hasClass('selectTag')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selectTag');
    getTagsNameArray.splice(getTagsNameArray.indexOf(item), 1);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('selectTag');
    getTagsNameArray.push(item);
  }
  console.log(getTagsNameArray.join(', '));
});

$('.q2-get-answer').on('click', function() {
  console.log(getTagsNameArray.join(', '));
})
```

```css
.product-multiple {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.product-multiple img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
.product-multiple img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.digestive-tool {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.digestive-tool .q1-answer li,
.digestive-tool .q2-answer li,
.digestive-tool .q3-answer li,
.digestive-tool .q4-answer li,
.digestive-tool .q5-answer li,
.digestive-tool .q6-answer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.digestive-tool .q1-get-answer,
.digestive-tool .q2-get-answer,
.digestive-tool .q3-get-answer,
.digestive-tool .q4-get-answer,
.digestive-tool .q5-get-answer,
.digestive-tool .q6-get-answer {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.digestive-tool .product,
.digestive-tool .product-multiple {
  display: inline-block;
}
.digestive-tool .product img,
.digestive-tool .product-multiple img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selectTag {
  border: 2px solid #00257a;
}
.q2-get-answer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  clear: left;
  border: 1px solid #900;
  background: #f00;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="q2">
  <label for="q2">What type of symptoms that your child has?</label>
  <div class="q2-answer" id="q2">
    <div class="product-multiple">
      <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="gassy">
      <div>Gassy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-multiple">
      <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="fussy">
      <div>Fussy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-multiple">
      <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="diahrea">
      <div>Diahrea</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-multiple">
      <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="spitup">
      <div>Spit Up</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-multiple">
      <img alt="doctor select" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/45921804/5/stock-photo-45921804-lake-view.jpg" name="constipation">
      <div>Constipation</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="q2-get-answer">
    Q3 click me
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/gcke1msx/9/)

Comment: Thanks, what's the use of  " , 1)" ?

Comment: (getTagsNameArray.indexOf(item), 1) use of "1" and also can we create a common function to be used for other questions ? please advice

Answer (score 1):

It's because you create a new `getTagsNameArray` array everytime you unselect a `$('.q2 .product-multiple')`. See the `else` statement in the click handler.

If I understand your question correctly, you want an array with the name attributes of the *selected* images? In that case:

- declare and create the `getTagsNameArray` outside the click handler
- on click of an image, add the name to the array
- on click again (so unselecting), find the name in the array and
  remove it.

https://jsfiddle.net/gcke1msx/7/

```
var getTagsNameArray = [];

$('.q2 .product-multiple').on('click', function(e) {
  // get the name of the image
  var name = $(this).find('img').attr('name');

  if($(this).hasClass('selectTag')) {
    // it was selected, now unselected
    // so remove its name from the array
    // see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript
    $(this).removeClass('selectTag');
    var index = getTagsNameArray.indexOf(name);
    getTagsNameArray.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    // selected it
    // and add name to array
    $(this).addClass('selectTag');
    getTagsNameArray.push(name);
  }
});

$('.q2-get-answer').on('click', function(){
  alert('selected: ' + getTagsNameArray.join(', '));      
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live demo 
https://jsfiddle.net/soonsuweb/4ea54xxu/3/

You can use **array.push, splice, join**.

```
var selected = [];

$('.q2 .product-multiple').on('click',function (e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('selectTag')){
        $(this).removeClass('selectTag');
        var name = $(this).find('img').attr('name');

        // remove the name from selected
        for (var i=0; i<selected.length; i++) {
            if (name === selected[i]) {
                selected.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        console.log("Should be Removed here.. ", name);
        console.log("Passing Value in Array - ", selected.join(', '))
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('selectTag');

        var name = $(this).find('img').attr('name');
        selected.push(name);
        console.log("Passing Value in Array - ", selected.join(', '))
    }
});

$('.q2-get-answer').on('click', function () {
    alert(selected.join(', '));
    console.log(selected.join(', '));
});
```